# async fetch react как получить данные до return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

Как получить данные по fetch до вызова return в react
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выводит в такой последовательности
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неее это не то у меня промисы они по определению уходят из потока, пробовал немедленно вызываему делать функцию но реакт не разрешает, выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Это именно то самое. Нельзя синхронно получить ответ от асинхронной функции. Никак. Никогда. Невозможно. Как ещё это донести?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Если только сделать запрос синхронным, но в данном случае у вас заблокируется интерфейс.

Запрос должен идти асинхронно и не тормозить рендеринг страницы. Вам нужно просто добавить, пока не пришел ответ, заглушку - `loading`.